# Edit string value based on a condition / another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm cleaning a large dataset and have a `Comments` column where I am commenting on changes made to the data.  I've provided a dummy sample set below as an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm using `tidyverse` packages.

**Data**:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17199, 17226, 17263, 17300, 
17346, 17504, 17508), class = "Date"), Skipper = c("Agatha", 
"Gertrude", "Julio", "Dylis", "Agatha", "Dylis", "Julio"), Success = c("No", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), Time = c(60L, 50L, 120L, 
30L, 100L, 120L, 40L), Comments = c("Pirates spotted.", "Illegal fishers spotted.", 
"Engine troubles.", "Lost fishing line.", NA, "Pirates spotted.", 
"Lost fishing line.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I'm looking to add text to string values in the `Comments` in relation to `Date`, without deleting values already present.

So for  `2017-04-07` and `2017-12-04` I would like to add `Iceberg spotted.` to the `Comments` for the respected `Date`'s.

```
        Date  Skipper Success Time                 Comments
1 2017-02-02   Agatha      No   60         Pirates spotted.
2 2017-03-01 Gertrude     Yes   50 Illegal fishers spotted.
3 2017-04-07    Julio     Yes  120         Engine troubles.
4 2017-05-14    Dylis     Yes   30       Lost fishing line.
5 2017-06-29   Agatha      No  100                     <NA>
6 2017-12-04    Dylis     Yes  120         Pirates spotted.
7 2017-12-08    Julio      No   40       Lost fishing line.
```

Using `stringr` and `str_c`  `R_example$Comments %>% str_c("Iceberg spotted")`

`[1] "Pirates spotted.Iceberg spotted"`

How can I select what dates to apply the above ^ code so that I can see changes made to the dataset for specified dates. Do I need to supply a `filter` or `if_else` function?

I have been trying with `case_when` but this replaces the existing values. I also could do this by creating another column then binding two columns together but I rather not do this.

```
R_example %>% 
  mutate(Comments = case_when(Date == "2017-04-07" & Date == "2017-12-04" ~ "Iceberg spotted.", 
                              TRUE ~ as.character(Comments)))
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

I forgot a little detail in my dataset. If I have multiple rows for a fishing trip and in the `Comments` column `<NA>` values, how can the string replace the `<NA>` values instead of adding to the `<NA>` value? Like so:

What my data looks like:

```
        Date  Skipper Success Time         Comments
1 2017-02-02   Agatha      No   60 Pirates spotted.
2 2017-02-02   Agatha      No   60             <NA>
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
        Date  Skipper Success Time                          Comments
1 2017-02-02   Agatha      No   60 Pirates spotted. Iceberg spotted.
2 2017-02-02   Agatha      No   60                  Iceberg spotted.
```

What I currently get from the code in answers below:

```
        Date  Skipper Success Time                          Comments
1 2017-02-02   Agatha      No   60 Pirates spotted. Iceberg spotted.
2 2017-02-02   Agatha      No   60                NAIceberg spotted.
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want additional rows with the new comments, or append the "Iceberg spotted" string to the existing comments as longer strings? Also, there is no "2017-04-17" in your sample data. Is that a typo, or do you mean you want a new row in that case?

Comment: Hi @Z.Lin I would like to append "Iceberg spotted" string to the existing strings for `2017-04-07` and `2017-12-04`. Making them longer :). That was a typo, sorry I've made an edit now!

Comment: There is a problem with your `case_when` example, as a date cannot be `2017-04-07` **and** `2017-12-04` simultaneously. You need an OR statement (`|` instead of `&`).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ifelse` in this case

```
dta %>% 
  mutate(
    Comments = if_else(Date %in% c(as.Date("2017-04-07"), as.Date("2017-12-04")), 
                       paste0(Comments, "Iceberg spotted"), 
                       Comments)
  )
```

Comment: so if the `Date` column is recognised as a `Date` and we have lots of dates to append strings we could do: `dta %>% mutate(Comments = if_else(Date %in% Date == "2017-04-07" | Date == "2017-12-04", paste0(Comments, "Iceberg spotted"), Comments))` ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution with base R:

```
# Find which rows will be changed
i <- which(df$Date %in% c(as.Date("2017-04-07"), as.Date("2017-12-04")))

# Modify the rows accordingly
df[i,"Comments"] <- paste(df[i,"Comments"], "Iceberg Spotted.")
```

Results in:

```
> df
        Date  Skipper Success Time                          Comments
1 2017-02-02   Agatha      No   60                  Pirates spotted.
2 2017-03-01 Gertrude     Yes   50          Illegal fishers spotted.
3 2017-04-07    Julio     Yes  120 Engine troubles. Iceberg Spotted.
4 2017-05-14    Dylis     Yes   30                Lost fishing line.
5 2017-06-29   Agatha      No  100                              <NA>
6 2017-12-04    Dylis     Yes  120 Pirates spotted. Iceberg Spotted.
7 2017-12-08    Julio      No   40                Lost fishing line.
```